# How to refresh a page from jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Im sending some data back and forth WP and at the same time Im trying to refresh the page from server side.

on functions.php

```
    function communicate_to_jquery() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
        wp_enqueue_script( Scriptname(), Scriptpath() , array('jquery'),'1.0' , true);
        $variable = 1;
        wp_localize_script( Scriptname(), 'ajax_var', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'),
            'mypostid' => get_the_ID(),
            'variable' => $variable,
            )
        );
    }        
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'communicate_to_jquery' );

    function ajax_response() {
        if ( isset( $_POST["myid"])) {
            $post_id = $_POST["myid"];
            $var = $_POST["ajaxvar"];
            echo 'var= ' . $var;

            //here I try to reload the page when the button is pressed on the client side
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0" />';
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            die();
        }
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_response', 'ajax_response');
```

then from a button I send the jQuery.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($j) {
            $j('#wp_button').on('click', function() {
                var data = {
                    action: 'response',
                    myid: ajax_var.mypostid,
                    ajaxvar: variable,
                };
                $.post(ajax_var.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        alert(response);        
                });
                return false;  
            });
    });
```

The data are correctly passed to WP, but the page is not refreshed (its only passed back into the alert). header("Refresh:0"); isnt working too.
I need to trigger the serverside refresh when the button is pressed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the server side refresh? There may be a better approach to the problem. Either way, you can not force the browser refresh from an AJAX call to the server, you will have to use something like `window.location` in your javascript.

Comment: Yes window.location is working indeed, but it is updating only the local active client. Im trying to update all the clients.

Comment: In that case you would need to add either an internal to your javascript that continually makes AJAX calls to the server, and on the server you can return true or false to determine whether you need to refresh or not. Here is some documentatio on setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval. Another option would be to load and then hook in to the Heartbeat API. I have never used that but here is a gist that shows one implementation https://gist.github.com/pippinsplugins/5991083

Comment: I meant interval, not internal

Comment: @czerspalace the refresh has to be done only when the button is pressed.
Basically I am trying to make this work
if ( isset( $_POST["myid"])) {
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI='http://example.com/'.$Path;
header("Refresh: 3; url=$URI"); 

but as you wrote this is not possible. I looked the hearbeat API there is no documentation. Can you be more specific about the setInterval solution? even if I place my function inside something like setInterval(ajaxCall, 100); function ajaxCall() {} how do I set the refresh on the server.
http://goo.gl/tn3dMU

Comment: Ok I am confused now. When a button is pressed, does every browser that has that page opened get refreshed, or just the one where the button was pushed?

Comment: When a button is pressed, every browser that has that page opened has to be refreshed, in that moment.

Comment: I used the setInterval solution: 

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(ajaxCall, 3000); 
function ajaxCall() { $('#load').load('reload.php?_=' +Math.random()).fadeIn("slow"); }
});

then on reload.php:
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" ); 
echo "User count is {$user_count}";

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($j) {
        $j('#wp_button').on('click', function() {
            var data = {
                action: 'response',
                myid: ajax_var.mypostid,
                ajaxvar: variable,
            };
            $.post(ajax_var.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    alert(response);   
                    location.reload();    
            });
            return false;  
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi MUT, yes location.reload(); works as expected, but Im trying to refresh the page from server side, so to update all the clients logged into that page.

Comment: @Elmiro Then send back some JSON data that instructs the JS handler to reload the page. Sending a meta refresh tag back is *not* the way to do it.